# Cannot get HTML of page

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

I want to get HTML using the HTTPWEBREQUEST for the following page:

http://inkdispatch.com/brother

Currently i am using :

```
 public static string getHTML(string url)
    {
        string responseData = "";
        try
        {
            //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Referer = "inkdispatch.com";
            request.CookieContainer = yummycookies;
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                yummycookies.Add(cook);
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;
        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

But i do not see anything i get response with no error just saying, Moved permenently and when i put the same link in browser it works. The link has a token attached to it, but i do get that from the main page , still same issue any help.

> UPDATE

I just set :

```
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

but i get error:

```
    Too many automatic redirections were attempted.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at inkdispatchcomScraper.Program.getHTML(String url)
```

And  i have fiddler open which shows its hitting the link again and again:

```
    #   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
72  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=00810c6a184e63149cdca848c7f02871 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
73  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=32cf6d38541a90658d39785b6cd64fbc 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
74  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=70d0d5eaa10175d74933ba00d47876f8 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
75  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=fa45c256a07a9450274269cfa4a4e64a 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
76  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=1fb7677a7e6ae0ca32a154ebcc42e043 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
77  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=39923f8100276b1c0fa5ccfb1f8d222c 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
78  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=fef228719b375ac012c4755793a0027a 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
79  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=5c2babf5e6b9b0834f605734441ba208 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
80  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=711bdefa3ca7cccebf63b9b8a3734be1 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
81  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=c55d1b6166994be1436c9473a1519abe 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
83  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=cc66424548f23c3c64b2e0054289283f 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
84  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=6f05f06093cd345d10ca729117994ac0 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
85  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=4a2ab4d3824c4850f544f28cd71bc1bb 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
86  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=6c9d0acd69fc22821014c7e3263da7b6 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
87  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=fff05b8df3a1488add36591a2687a830 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
88  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=b10facbe8bc9b9a355fe648649067f98 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
89  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=8b767c98491178e54d12b4e85ff02b2e 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
90  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=9f0b8cb119fee9a4e276bcae5f13772d 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
91  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=943076fabf058eb1316cfa86aadb1dec 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
92  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=8bd0335032a58b9c399706cd9c695901 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
93  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=a1ba5e21f0af2750d398484e063e8303 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
94  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=e704b2951b1d136c195fd02ad4abec93 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612           
95  301 HTTP    inkdispatch.com /brother?zenid=6d606d0785f19c17ccb1868577a9d546 0   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  text/html   inkdispatchcomscraper.vshost:4612
```

> ANOTHER UPDATE

I have seen when i open it in IE it uses the redirect to /brother but in case of code it gets another ZENID ant forward to that and this keeps happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`

**EDIT**

And for your **second** question, declare `yummycookies` as below.

```
public static string getHTML(string url)
{
   CookieContainer yummycookies = new CookieContainer();
   ...
}
```

Comment: But It works correctly on my PC. (I just had to declare `static CookieContainer yummycookies = new CookieContainer();`)

Comment: which link are you hitting? it works perfect for http://inkdispatch.com/  but no other link.

Comment: No other link? Are you sure? it works for me `http://inkdispatch.com/brother` `http://www.google.com`  `http://stackoverflow.com` etc.

Comment: I meant to say no other link in the site, for every other link then the hompage, keeps hitting itself again and again until i get the error stated above.Only the homepage return HTML fine , :( .Any suggestion.

Comment: Can this be possible they put a check on ip on some countries to avoid ?Then again i get the html on IE so its very confusing.

Comment: @confusedMind I finally got your `Too many automatic redirections were attempted`. It is related with your cookie container. I'll update the answer.

Comment: its still same for me :(, do you have email id i will send you the code so you can run to see,?or skype maybe not necessary just if you have free time :).

Comment: @confusedMind I already use your code posted above. If I remove the `yummycookies` lines, I get your error.

Comment: This is because i get the link parsing HTML of main page : and i get a link like = http://inkdispatch.com/brother?zenid=3f9fdd83f8efdc764edfc9d54608e2b2 
And it doesnot work , and i also checked with :http://inkdispatch.com/brother still does not work . NOt sure whats happening here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10099/discussion-between-l-b-and-confusedmind)

Comment: The request i make is like this:

Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)
Referer: inkdispatch.com
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: inkdispatch.com


but it should aslo have a field at the end:Cookie: zenid=9ea4d211ba2aa64cbaa148df5de4ab10


That is causing the issue nt sure why the field is not adding

Comment: I did , it with the obvious help here but also by replicating every thing .

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to test your code, it failed, but another test i found the following error "Too many automatic redirections were attempted."

While updating your code and test it again, it works well on your provided url, html fetched properly. code is here.

```
public static string GetHtml2(string urlAddr)
{
    if (urlAddr == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlAddr))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("urlAddr");
    }
    else
    {
        string result;

        //1.Create the request object
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddr);
        //request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        //request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 200;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //2.Add the container with the active
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();


        //3.Must assing a cookie container for the request to pull the cookies
        request.CookieContainer = cc;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this will be ok.

Comment: thank you same issue i think some internet setting on my side maybe :it worked when i did thi :

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

                WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;

                //Add the Accept-Language header (for Danish) in the request.
                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language:en-US");


                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Cookie", "zenid=9ea4d211ba2aa64cbaa148df5de4ab10");

Comment: In most cases if you enabled encoding "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate" live fetching won't work especially in cases when targetted website enabled this type of encoding.

Comment: Yes i do not use that at all , but in this case i had to replicate everything thn only it worked.