# c# App skip after reading JSON response

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I been trying to use an online API that returns an a json.
I am using winform application at the moment.

So far i tried

```
WebClient cHttp = new WebClient();
string htmlCode = cHttp.DownloadString(path);  <--------

///-----------And then this

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.Accept = "application/json";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); <-----
```

Where i point the arrow to, the program doesn't crash it just hit that line and then skip all the code below it. Then my form open without running my entire code. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use try-catch block, and you'll see an error:

```
try
{
    WebClient cHttp = new WebClient();
    string htmlCode = cHttp.DownloadString(path); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: I dont get it... the path works when i input it into a browser. So this is the error in visual studio
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.


   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)

Comment: @Photonic and here is your problem. You have no access and you must to pass credetials like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2w99hxh(v=vs.110).aspx (it may depends) or like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680718/domain-credentials-for-a-webclient-class-dont-work

Comment: Thanks i think i got pass error (401) but would you know how to fix this next error. A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
System.Net.WebException: Too many automatic redirections were attempted.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)

Comment: If i use a webBrowser class to navigate to that path, it gives me an option box to save it as json file to drive, which i dont want, so how do it just save it into a string?

Comment: @Photonic the problem is your path variable is not final path. You should find the end :)

Comment: Thanks for putting time and effort Photonic... Anyway i found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164259/cannot-get-html-of-page
This seems to work

Answer (score 0):

It jumps out of your method. You must catch the exception and return null object. or find the error.